# How to add a character at start and end of every word in NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsstring

Suppose i have this:

```
NSString *temp=@"its me";
```

Now suppose i want ' **"** ' in start and end of every word, how can i achieve it to get the result like this:

```
"its" "me"
```

Do i have to use regular expressions?

Comment: pseudo code `replace("\\b", "\"")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have punctuation inside the string, splitting with a space might not be enough.

Use the [**word boundary `\b`**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html): it matches both the leading and trailing word boundaries (that is, it will match an empty space right between word and non-word characters and also at the start/end of the string if followed/preceded with a word character.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *myText = @"its me";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\b" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive|NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:myText options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [myText length]) withTemplate:@"\""];
NSLog(@"%@", modifiedString); // => "its" "me"
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/wRHrvW)

See more details on the [regex syntax in Objective C here](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like,

```
 NSString *str = @"its me";

NSMutableString *resultStr = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

for (int i = 0; i < arr.count; i++) {

    NSString *tempStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\"",arr[i]];

    resultStr = [resultStr stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",tempStr]];

}
NSLog(@"result string is : %@",resultStr);
```

Hope this will help :)